# Regex for sub-domain

Tags: regex

I have several sub-domains configured to a IIS website. I would like to parse the incoming requests in ARR. I would like to match a specific sub-domain that would capture all these different scenarios

```
http://abc.example.com
https://abc.example.com
http://abc.example.com/xyz
https://abc.example.com/xyz
http://abc.example.com/xyz?q=123
https://abc.example.com/xyz?q=123
```

I have tried a few things but they don't seem to work and searches only reveal how to catch sub-domains and not just a sub-domain.

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output for the e.g. given?

Comment: @Matt.G ..  i have corrected my urls to be on separate lines. I want the regex to catch all these different variations which include abc.example.com with or without the http/https variation.

Comment: @Jan .. thanks for the help.. hope you have a nice day

Comment: @Gabbar: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/n6Lw60/1 ?

Comment: @Jan .. again thanks for the help .. i will give it a try .. seems to pass everything i tried

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
http(?:s)?:\/\/(abc)\..*
```

Comment: This is a really crappy expression, you neither need the first non-capturing group nor the second capturing group.

Comment: @Jan, I agree with your findings. You could add it as an answer, or I'll edit mine.